# Does SSH Key-Based Authentication Depend on The User Account?

Tags: ssh, rsa

I would like to know if the public key depends on the used account. In other words, do I really have to use the **same account** on the server and the client when I add my public key (id_rsa.pub) in authorized_keys on the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accounts don't matter. All that matters is that the client key is in the server account's `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: So, when a message is encrypted by this public key on the server, how can the client found the right private key to decrypt it if each user on the client have generated one?

Comment: When you open the connection, public key encryption is used to authenticate the client and generate a session key. The session key is used from then on, and each connection has a different session key.

Comment: But to authenticate the client machine the public key must check all the private keys in the account's client, key by key, to find the right one...?

Comment: Yes. Use `ssh -v` and you'll see that it sends each key until the server accepts it. You can tell it which key to send to each server in your `.ssh/config`.

Comment: Ok. It's clear. Thank you very match for your help.